# ParentItemNotFoundException when syncing project with sitecore using TDS

Tags: tds

I am using TDS and visual studio 2017. I'm working with other people, so I need to constantly get latest first then get my sitecore items and sync them using TDS.

When i click on "sync with sitecore", a list of all the differences between my project and my sitecore instance appear.
example
[image]

I choose to add them to Sitecore, and click "Do updates", but I'm met with this error
[image]

Has anyone run into this error before? if yes, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have the parent item on your content tree?

Comment: i have one of my own, but apparently it wont match its ID and is expecting the parent item for the items created by other devs that i'm trying to get from the server

Comment: have you also checked this: [Sync with Sitecore Error: ParentItemNotFoundException](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/3190)? 

_Sounds strange but got this resolved by clearing the temp files and then bouncing the IIS._

Comment: @monkey.dsc yes i tried that and it also didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have some parent item which should be synced first as well. Try to find it first, then sync it, then try again with problematic one. It’s like trying to sync child without information about the parent.

Comment: I had to unify the parent items across all our machines, by only letting one of us creating the parent items/folders, and then we all get it and work on its children items successfully. thank you for your answer though :)